# submit form as soon as file was selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I have following html form:

```
<form method="POST"  action="uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="file" class="file" name="file"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
```

I see two things on page
1 - file selector
2 - upload button

I want to avoid submit button and form should be submitted right after file was selected.

Can you help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe this helps you:

```
$('.file').change(function(){
    $('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

with javascript..

```
<form method="POST" name="myform" action="uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" class="file" name="file" onchange="document.forms['myform'].submit();"/>
</form>
```